# Upload config amazone s3 not showing

Tags: assets

Just installed the new Assets module and configured an amazone s3 location. However the location is not showing up in the assets module (upload files list).

When configured as a fieldtype I can select the directory (s3) to upload to during configuration. But while editing an entry I get a blank upload files modal.

Answer (score 3):

You need to **Update Indexes** after adding the new S3 source.